# Google Fusion Table Double Click (dblClick)

Tags: events, google-maps, click, google-fusion-tables

I am using a Fusion Table to overlay counties on some states.  On a single click, I display a popup showing the detail measures for the county.  I was asked to drill into more information (drill-through to another report/map) on a dblclick event.  I understand that the map fires the dblclick event all the time except when the dblclick is on a marker or an overlay.  Now with that long introduction said... can anyone help me get the dblclick

```
google.maps.event.addListener(ftLayer, 'dblclick', function(e) {
        var url ="http://the_URL";
        window.location.href = url;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

dblclick is not currently enabled on Fusion Tables Layers. Please feel free to open a feature request:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list