# Imitating Mouse click - point with known coordinates on a fusion table layer - google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have been making a script using a fusion table's layer in `google maps`.

I am using geocoder and get the coordinates of a point that I need.

I put a script that changes the style of a polygon from the fusion table when you click on it, using the `google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(e) {});`

I would like to use the same function that I call in the case of a click on the layer, but this time with a click with the coordinates that I got.

I have tried `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', {latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(42.701487,26.772308)});`

As well as the example here > [Google Fusion Table Double Click (dblClick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843783/google-fusion-table-double-click-dblclick)

I have tried changing map with layer...

I am sorry if my question is quite stupid, but I have tried many options.

P.S. I have seen many post about getting the info from the table, but I do not need that. I want to change the style of the `KML` element in the selected row, so I do not see it happening by a query.

Here is the model of my script:

```
        function initialize() 
        {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            suppressInfoWindows:true,
            map : map,
                query : {
                    select: 'Местоположение',
                from: '12ZoroPjIfBR4J-XwM6Rex7LmfhzCDJc9_vyG5SM'
                }
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(e) {
            SmeniStilRaionni(layer,e);
                marker.setMap(null);
            });

            }

    function SmeniStilRaionni(layer,e)
            {
                ...
            }

    function showAddress(address) 
        {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  var point = results[0].geometry.location;
                  //IMITATE THE CLICK
                  }
            });
        }
```

In response to **geocodezip**

This way you hide all the other elements... I do not wish that. It is like if I want to change the border of the selected element. And I do not wish for a new layer.
In the function that I use now I push the `style` of the `options` of the `layer` and then set the option. I use the `e` from `google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(e));` by inserting `e.row['Name'].value` inside the `where` rule.

I would like to ask you if there is any info on the `e` variable in `google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(e));`

***I found out how to get the results I wanted:***

For my query after I get the point I use this:

```
var queryText ="SELECT 'Районен съд','Окръжен съд','Апелативен съд','Местоположение'  FROM "+FusionTableID+" WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(\'Местоположение\', CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + point.toUrlValue(6) + "),0.5));";
queryText = encodeURIComponent(queryText);          
document.getElementById("vij query").innerHTML = queryText;
var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);
```

And then I get these results:

```
var rsyd = response.getDataTable().getValue(0,0);
var osyd =  response.getDataTable().getValue(0,1);
var apsyd = response.getDataTable().getValue(0,2);
```

And then, I use the following:

```
      where: "'Районен съд' = '"+rsyd+"'",
```

Which is the same as:

```
      where: "'Районен съд' = '"+e.row['Районен съд'].value+"'",
```

in the click function.

This is a working solution for my problem.

**But still, I cannot find a way to Imitate a Mouse click.**

Comment: Down this road lies maddness - I've never come up with a workable solution and Google Maps API team members I asked visibly shuddered when they heard what I was doing.

Comment: So they never answered clearly :/ Hm... I'll keep hoping for a while...
Thanks for sharing that experience, since I'm always the one complaining that things can't happen... and people always tell me they can :D

Comment: You need to query the table for the polygon that contains the returned coordinates, you can't simulate a click unless you already know all the information that it will return from the table.  [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_geocoder_PointInPolygon.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to toggle the colour of picked polygons on a Fusion Tables layer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738751/how-to-toggle-the-colour-of-picked-polygons-on-a-fusion-tables-layer)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I know how to toggle the colours of a clicked polygon on the layer. My function SmeniStilRaionni(layer,e) does that job. But it expects an "e", that I do not know how to get by a query to the table, if I have the coordinates of the point I am searching for. That's why I thought it will be much easier if click is simulated on the point. If it is not possible, then comes next: I do not know how to find any connection between the E in the function on click and the possible results of a query of a point in the kmls in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this:  the data(row) for the layers will be requested via AJAX when you click on a layer.

In theory it's possible to select a geometry(polygon) by a given LatLng, the geometry-library has a method for this: [google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#poly).

Unfortunately the FusionTableAPI does not support such queries(`ST_CONTAINS`), you cannot select a row by supplying a LatLng and selecting the rows where the geometry contains the LatLng.

So what you can do: create a copy of the table that contains the columns needed to select a row(`Община`...the distinct value, and `Местоположение`.... the geometry). This copy may be requested via AJAX, but when the FusionTable will not be modified anymore I would suggest to use a hardcoded copy.

**What to do now when you want to simulate the click:**

Iterate over all rows of the copy, use the mentioned `containsLocation()`-method to check if the geometry(`Местоположение`) contains the LatLng and when it does apply the query by using the value of the distinct column `Община` .

Of course it would take some time to check all the geometries, but the FusionTable is not very large, it should be a possible approach in your case.

Here is a demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/sSwj3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/sSwj3/)

The size of the stored data is  approximately 500kb, you should store the data in an external script, so they may be cached.

You may notice that the highligthning of the selected layer will be much faster when triggered via the links, because there will no data be requested via AJAX. When the highlightning of the selected feature is the only thing you need you may ommit the observation of the layer-click completely and observe the map-click instead. Use the returned LatLng to retrieve the selected row from the data and set the style:

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/swdX8/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/swdX8/)

Comment: I already have a separate query that gets all the data needed.
The simulation of the click was needed so that a separate query is avoided.

Comment: I've just uploaded the current script. Sorry for the mess - [HERE](http://fusiontabletest.hit.bg/rabotismarkera-kopie.html) .
I made the effect I wanted. You can try out by searching for Varna / Варна or Sofia / София. 
The thing is that I wanted to avoid all that and ease things a lot by simulating a click on the point, instead of making the query.

Comment: You may write a thousand times what you wan't, when the used API doesn't support the desired feature you may use a workaround or leave it. BTW: your link didn't work.(I also don*t need to try it because I've supplied 2 working fiddles) . Furthermore, your latest comment above: *But it expects an "e", that I do not know how to get by a query to the table, if I have the coordinates of the point I am searching for*....what do you have, what do you know, what do you want(except that you want to avoid work )?

Comment: I didn't have any idea where to host the html and js together. It loads for me.
I wrote what I wanted so many times, because I got responses for what I did not. There were workarounds given or suggestions that were off topic for me. I asked specifically for the click. I have a workaround. But it would save people a lot of time, if there was a way to do the click. And the thing is that geocodezip, who happen to have many great examples of scripts, did not approve that there is no way to do that. But even if they did, there might be someone, who knows how to do it. Impossible proves to be wrong.

Comment: And in my post, I have asked if there is any info on `e` in `google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(e));`, since `e.row['Name'].value` is the only known use I have seen. And in the case of making a query to the table, Google says the row number could be obtained in some yet unknown way for me. It could be possible that this row number is connected to the `e`. This way the two paths to the click could be synchronized.

Comment: *I didn't have any idea where to host the html and js together. It loads for me.*: http://jsfiddle.net might be a good start. *But it would save people a lot of time, if there was a way to do the click*: There is no implemented way, that's a fact.

Comment: *Google says the row number could be obtained in some yet unknown way for me* : there is a `rowid` set internally for each row. This rowid may be requested via the FusionTableAPI([example](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=Select%20col0,rowid%20from%2012ZoroPjIfBR4J-XwM6Rex7LmfhzCDJc9_vyG5SM&key=insertYourKeyHere)...use your own key) . But this rowid will not help you, it may not be used for queries in FusionTable-styles.

Comment: I put a huge database in a separate js file and that's why I did not use jsfiddle. Here is a link without the database /autocomplete will not work now/ - [THE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/5wgjX/). I have no idea if the script I use could lead to overload or other problems, since I am not a pro at all. But I believe, that I have found an easier workaround. Try searching Varna, Plovdiv, Sofia...